# Null parameter alternative C# 6.0

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have seen new feature in C# 6 which allows code to skip `if` statements for `null` checks.

For example:

```
return p?.ToString();
```

How can this be done for calling a method to which `p` needs to be passed as parameter (without old `if`/`else`)?

The way I would normally write this with C# pre-6:

```
 p != null ? callmethod(p) : null
```

is there something better in C# 6?

Comment: There is definitely nothing to take care of the "OrEmpty` part.

Comment: sorry mate, for a method call you still do it the old way.

Comment: The best available is `callmethod(p ?? string.Empty)`. For limited values of "best".

Comment: @ClickRick I tend to agree but op wants a way to never invoke method if the parameter is null. no such feature exists.

Comment: Consumers of `callMethod` shouldn't care/know about what validation rules method have - they just passing arguments which satisfy method contract/signature. In case when you get `p` from somewhere else and want validate it before passing further - it is better for readability that you show your intents by validating it as you did in "old way"

Comment: Your question is unclear - your first example has a `return` statement, yet your second example is only a single-branch `if` statement - what should happens if the `if` expression is `false`?

Comment: Do you want to avoid if-else syntax? You could use the ternary operator `return string.IsNullOrEmpty(p) ? null : callmethod(p)`. If you want to avoid repeating p, you would need to write an extension method.

Answer (score 8):

You can use an extension method - which you can generalize to any situation. This works because C# allows extension methods to work with `null` values for the `this` parameter (surprisingly!), whereas with normal instance methods you would otherwise get a `NullReferenceException`.

Here's something similar to what I used in my own projects before we had the `?.` "safe-navigation" operator in C# 6:

```
public static class Extensions
{    
    public static TRet NullSafeCall<TValue,TRet>( this TValue value, Func<TValue,TRet> func )
        where TValue : class
        where TRet : class
    {
        if( value != null ) return func( value );
        return null;
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
return p.NullSafeCall( callmethod );
```

It also supports the use of lambdas if you need to pass more than 1 argument into your subsequent `func`:

```
String foo = "bar";
return p.NullSafeCall( v => callmethod2( v, foo ) );
```

In your example you used `String.IsNullOrEmpty` instead of `!= null`, which can be added like so:

```
public static class Extensions
{    
    public static TRet NullSafeCall<TValue,TRet>( this TValue value, Func<TValue,Boolean> guard, Func<TValue,TRet> func )
        where TValue : class
        where TRet : class
    {
        if( guard( value ) ) return func( value );
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
return p.NullSafeCall( v => String.IsNullOrEmpty( v ), v => callmethod( v ) );
```

And of course, you can chain it:

```
return p
    .NullSafeCall( callmethod2 )
    .NullSafeCall( callmethod3 )
    .NullSafeCall( v => callmethod4( v, "foo", bar ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

About Null-conditional operators you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#null-conditional-operators).

The alternative for parameters' checking for `null` is the `??` operator which is used in the following way:

```
someMethod(val??"0");// this means that "0" will be passed as a value if val is null
```

But this is no way connected to checking for empty string. So you will have to check for empty string anyway if the `value` is not allowed to be it.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK using the if statement is good as it expresses your intent quite clearly. An alternative approach, alleviating this feature is by creating an extension method on the string "callmethod"

```
public static class extension
{
     public static void callmethod (this string myInput)
     {}
}
```

and as such, you would be able to do

```
p?.callmethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without 'if else', you can do that by using following code-

```
p!=string.Empty?callmethod(p):"";
```

Comment: This is not valid line at all without any operator checking the result of this. But even if the operator is added this is just calling `callmethod(p)`  and checking if `p` is not equal to the returning result of `callmethod(p)`.